# Работа с итераторами в  Java (ArrayList or another collection class)

Tags: java

Есть ArrayList из 10 элементов.
Как перебрать с 4 по 8 элемент при помощи итераторов ?

В с++ у меня это не создавало таких проблем))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex).iterator();
```

Или через for-each:

```
for(Type element : list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex) {
  // do something
}
```

Обратите внимание на то, что subList возвращает представление части списка с элемента с индексом fromIndex, по элемент toIndex не включая последний.

Comment: Спасибо , идеально.

Answer (score 1):

Интерфейс *List* имеет метод *get(int position)*.

Если уж прям совсем хочется именно итераторами, то опять-таки, интерфейс *List* содержит метод *listIterator()* и *listIterator(int location)*, возвращающие итератор с начала коллекции и с определённой позиции соответственно.

Comment: Товарищи анонимные минусаторы такие забавные :)

Comment: Про это я знаю, дополните пожалуйста ваш ответ.
Вот такой же код не сработает.

ListIterator<Float> i_begin  = array.listIterator(4);
ListIterator<Float> i_end    = array.listIterator(8);

for(ListIterator<Float> i = i_begin ;i!=i_end;)
{   
  Float test = i.next();
}

Как сделать код рабочим?

Comment: И всё же, чем вам вариант с get:

    for (int i = 4; i < 8; ++i) {
        final float value = array.get(i);
    }

не нравится?

Ну а по поводу итераторов - у них есть методы bool hasNext() и T next() - дальше, думаю, сами разберётесь.

Comment: Спасибо , вы мне ничем не помогли.

Comment: а как красиво это делается в с++? и откуда берутся +2 аргумента в функцию?

Comment: Что-то у вас не так с архитектурой, видимо.

Comment: Все там нормально с архитектурой.
В с++ передаются только 4 итератора от массивов + 5 итератор от массива ошибок .
А в жаве придется тащить 2 аррея и 4 индекса + итератор от массива ошибок.